# Getting Refresh Token in Azure B2C, with Azure AD App being the third party IDP

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a Web App and the users authenticate via Azure B2C. We added an Azure AD App as Claims Provider. So our users should be able to login via local accounts and Azure AD accounts. For the ones that login via Azure AD App we'd like to get the access and refresh token, to be able to make calls to the Microsoft Graph. Getting the access token works, but the refresh token is not sent.

This is the custom policy TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>azuread</Domain>
  <DisplayName>azure AD app</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AADCommon-OpenIdConnect">
      <DisplayName>Azure AD</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your Azure AD account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">CLIENT-ID</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid profile offline_access</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
        <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_azureadappkey"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        ...
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderRefreshToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:refresh_token}"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        ...
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

And signup_signin.xml looks like this:

```
<RelyingParty>
<DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
<TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
  <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="idp_access_token"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderRefreshToken" PartnerClaimType="idp_refresh_token"/>
  </OutputClaims>
  <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

In the claims of the user, there is the access token in `idp_access_token`, but nothing for `idp_refresh_token`.

What do I have to change to get the Refresh Token as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that you need to switch protocol for the Technical Profile from "OpenIdConnect" to "OAuth2" and specify the various endpoints yourself:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AADCommon-OpenIdConnect">
          <DisplayName>Company Azure AD</DisplayName>
          <Description>Login with your Company Azure AD</Description>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2"/>
          <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token</Item>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">access_token</Item>
            <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">CLIENT-ID</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">offline_access openid</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_azureadappkey"/>
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="surname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" DefaultValue="azuread" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderRefreshToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:refresh_token}"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

That way, the refresh token ends up in the user's claims:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I looked at this last year and it's not possible, as only the access token is returned.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy